# Chebyshev's Estimates for residue classes: Is my solution correct?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I want to show that:

$$\psi(x;q,a) \asymp x$$

i.e. I want to show that $\psi(x; q, a) \ll x$ and $\psi(x; q, a) \gg x$

$\psi(x; q, a)$ is the Chebyschev's Second function in residue class a mod q.

In other words, $$\psi(x, q, a) = \sum_{n \leq x}\Lambda(n).\mathbf{1}_{q,a}(n)$$

where, $$\mathbf{1}_{q,a}(n) = \begin{cases}
       1 &\quad\ n = a \text{ mod }q \\
       0 &\quad\ n \neq a \text{ mod }q \\
     \end{cases}$$

and

$\Lambda$ is the von mangoldt function.

On pages 83-84 of the notes: [Notes](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Ehildebr/tex/examples/books/ant.pdf)

$\psi(x) \asymp x$ has been proven. Therefore we know $\psi(x) \ll x$ and $\psi(x) \gg x$

Now,

it is simple to see that:

$$\psi(x) - \psi(x; q, a) \geq 0 \implies \psi(x; q, a) \leq \psi(x) \ll x \implies \psi(x; q, a) \ll x$$

Now, I do not know how to show $\psi(x; q, a) \gg x$

I have tried hard to solve this but I am unable to.

Any pointer towards a possible direction would be very helpful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that this lower bound is quite a bit more difficult than the corresponding lower bound for $\psi(x)$ itself; by way of analogy, both lower bounds imply that there are infinitely many primes being counted, but it is far harder to prove that there are infinitely many primes congruent to $a$ (mod $q$) than just to prove that there are infinitely many primes.

Unless I'm missing something, I don't think there's a substantially easier way to prove $\psi(x;q,a) \gg x$ then to prove Dirichlet's theorem (on the Dirichlet density of such primes)—for example, equation (6.8) on page 181 of the (excellent) notes you linked—and then use partial summation starting from $\psi(x;q,a) = \int_1^x t \,dS_{a,q}(t)$.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Yes, the lower bound is a bit difficult. I also thought along the same line initially but I have been attempting to solve the problem without using the more sophisticated machinery used in residue class situations like the Derichlet Characters. However, I think I have a solution now, which I have put in the question as an edit. I would greatly appreciate if you could give a look and judge it if it is correct. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately not: you wrote that $\Lambda(n)$ is the divisor sum of $\log n$, but it's the other way around. Note that if that calculation were correct, then it would imply there are infinitely many primes congruent to $a$ (mod $q$); it's quite unlikely that nobody would have seen such a short proof before now.

Comment: Oh yeah! You're correct. I made a error. Thanks for pointing it out. I'll remove the edit.